# Google App Script Function: Return Drive Filename from File URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've searched extensively for an answer to this, but have not had much luck. I think it should be a fairly simple answer. Here's what I'm trying to do:

- I have a list of (other) Google Sheets document URLs in a Google Sheet.
- I'd like to have a simple function that loads the URL in each line and returns the file name.
- To illustrate, if the URLs are in A2:A10, a user could input a custom function like =GetFileName(A2) and it would return the file name corresponding to the Google Sheet URL that is in A2.

Here's the code that I have thus far, but it's returning an error, " TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.openByURL is not a function (line 3)."

```
function getFileName(fileURL) {
  
  var GetFile = SpreadsheetApp.openByURL(fileURL);
  var GetName = GetFile.getName();
  return GetName;

}
```

UPDATE *************

Here's the code that worked for me. Basically, it loops through the sheet with IDs to pull file names. Not the most efficient, but works for relatively short lists just fine.

```
function getFileName() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // DocumentIDs are listed in the 'tool' sheet
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("tool");
  // Find the last row
  var LastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();

  //Loop Begins
  //Initializing variable assumes that the first valid Drive ID is in the 3rd row.
  for(var i = 3; i < LastRow; i++) {
  
    // Get the Document ID. This gets the Document ID
    var LookupID = targetSheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();

    // Get the Filename
    var FileOpen = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(LookupID));
    var FileName = FileOpen.getName();
    
    // Write the FileName in the second column
    targetSheet.getRange(i,2).setValue(FileName);
    
    Logger.log(i);
    Logger.log(LookupID);
    Logger.log(FileName);
  
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestion:**

You can try this script together with using clickable image to act as a button for the function to run the script below:

```
function convertURLtoSheetName() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getValue(); 
  var getSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(cell).getName();
  var seturl = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(getSheetName).setLinkUrl(cell).build();
  ss.getActiveCell().setRichTextValue(seturl);

}
```

[image]

Here is how you assign a script function to an image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Custom Functions Cannot open other spreadsheets (SpreadsheetApp.openById() or SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()).

[reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that. In that case, I guess the best approach would be to just create an array with all the URLs and get the file names in a loop. That make sense?